# Mongodb How to execute collstats on all collections in a database

Tags: mongodb

I'm attempting to execute the collstats command on all collections in a database with this code:

```
db=getSiblingDB("test");
var collectns = db.getCollectionNames();
function myfunc(collname) {
   db.runCommand({collstats : collname });
   print(collname);
}
collectns.forEach(myfunc);
```

The print statement is working fine and prints all collection names, but there is no output and no errors from the collstats command. I've tried many variations with no luck. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With much trial and error this line:

```
db.runCommand({collstats : collname });
```

was changed to:

```
printjson(db.runCommand({collstats : collname }));
```

and the `collstat` output displays.